# How to click UIView Button of NavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem

```
UIView *leftButtonItemView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

UIImageView *addButtonEmptyImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[addButtonEmptyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];
addButtonEmptyImage.frame = CGRectMake(15,0,20,30);

[leftButtonItemView addSubview:addButtonEmptyImage];
[addButtonEmptyImage release];

UIImageView *correctButtonEmptyImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[correctButtonEmptyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];
correctButtonEmptyImage.frame = CGRectMake(50,0,20,30);

[leftButtonItemView addSubview:correctButtonEmptyImage];
[correctButtonEmptyImage release];

UIBarButtonItem *leftButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButtonItemView];
[leftButtonItemView release];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButtonItem;
[leftButtonItem release];
```

This is some source of my app. I know NavigationItem has two buttons(left and right). But I hope to make three buttons. so I make one button which use navigationItem and the other button which use a blank view. I want to click correctButtonEmptyImage. But this is in leftButtonItemView. namely, If I clicked the view which contains two images, I woud have seen leftButtonItemView not correctButtonEmptyImage. help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIButtons instead of UIImageViews as the subviews of your container view (leftButtonItemView). Use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to assign action methods to the buttons.

PS: Please don't just say "It doesn't work" in your question. Tell us more specifically what works and what doesn't. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I'm so sorry about it.